# Custom guice module in atmosphere

Tags: guice, atmosphere

Is there a way to define custom guice modules that are being picked up by atmosphere? I've found `GuiceObjectFactory` and within it the private class `AtmosphereModule` which does not help here.

The goal is to create guice provider bindings that can be used within an atmosphere application.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

There is not much more to add. As stated above my goal is to be able to define custom guice providers like

```
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements Provider<ObjectMapper> {

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper get() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

I've followed the instructions from [the official wiki](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Configuring-Atmosphere's-Classes-Creation-and-Injection) on how to enable guice for DI. The question is now if there is a way to bind my custom provider (like in https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProviderBindings).

Comment: Could you please give some more details? Frameworks used, what you tried so far? Right now, I have no idea what this is all about ... and I might not be the only one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after looking at the code again the answer was quite obvious. You can create a injector yourself and add it to the serlvet context during the bootstrap process, it will then be picked up by atmosphere.

```
Config.Builder builder = new Config.Builder();
builder.resource(MyResource.class)
        .port(8080)
        .host("localhost")
        .servletContextAttribute(Injector.class.getName(), Guice.createInjector(new CustomModule()))
        .build();
```